# Report Viewer Control Version 10 Not Paging

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

I recently upgraded my report viewer control from version 9 to version 10, and now its paging controls don't work. Whether I use the next button, last page button, or type in a page number, after postback the page is always reset to one.

I know the dataset has more than one page of data, and it is even returned to me in full if I export to excel via the report toolbar.

The Chrome javascript console shows no errors, and inspection of the postback generated by the paging control in Fiddler yields nothing obviously wrong. When I manually set the page number to 2 and inspect the form fields in Fiddler, I see a form field that looks like the CurrentPage property, and its value is indeed 2. However when reloading the page, the number is reset to 1.

The report viewer displays a local rdlc report. I opened it in VS2010 and opted to upgrade its format, just in case, to no avail.

I have tried with async rendering on and off, no good.

I am using an AjaxControlToolkit script manager on my master page, instead of asp:scriptManager.

A possibly related issue: I was initially getting an assembly load error looking for System.Web.Ajax. I was unable to find this dll in the add reference dialog. I ended up copying it into my bin folder, from another machine on which this problem didn't occur.

Answer (score 0):

See Charles Wang's response on [MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/1ff5b061-5b33-43dd-ba48-66b52bf73bdc).

> I opened a case with MS, and this is a
>   BUG with the ReportViewer control for
>   SQL 2008.  They said this is fixed
>   with R2, but I can't confirm that as
>   I'm only on 2008 sp1

Comment: "They said this is fixed with R2, but I can't confirm that as I'm only on 2008 sp1". I am running SQL Server 2008 R2, but I fail to see how this is relevant: the bug appears to be in the control itself. To my knowledge, there is only one distribution of the 2010 reportviewer control, and there's no "R2" of the control. Can anybody shed light on this?

Comment: "R2" refers to the second release of SQL Server 2008. Keep in mind that SSRS is still a SQL Server product and that the ReportViewer is developed for SSRS. That said, each version of ReportViewer is shipped/released with each version of SQL Server. So what Charles was saying is that the version of ReportViewer that was released to be most compatible with SQL Server 2008 R2 may include a fix for the paging bug, but he doesn't know for sure. Either way, it's a reported bug for Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

To me was happen the same, I resolved this issue set the property `PageCountMode=Actual` on the Report viewer control.